# Beautiful Soup's XML parser can't handle Boolean attributes?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to get proper text fields with Beautiful Soup's XML parser in the document below?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <header class="site-header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac tempus magna. Morbi maximus enim eu dolor ultricies, quis vestibulum lacus finibus. Maecenas sed fermentum nisi. Sed nec dignissim mi. Curabitur vel magna faucibus, ultrices tortor quis,
      gravida metus. Fusce in nisi et ligula feugiat pharetra. Nam sed sapien auctor, egestas sem nec, hendrerit libero. Nulla in semper ligula. Vivamus commodo pulvinar luctus. In ac vehicula felis. In nec bibendum nulla.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that the presence of Boolean `itemscope` forces the `itemtype` attribute and its value to get moved into the text node:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('bs4-issue-xml.html', 'r') as f:
    html_raw = ''.join(f.read())

soup_lxml = BeautifulSoup(html_raw, 'lxml')
soup_xml = BeautifulSoup(html_raw, 'xml')

assert 'schema.org' not in soup_lxml.header.text
assert 'schema.org' not in soup_xml.header.text  # assertion fails
```

Here's what is carried over into the `header.text`:

```
In [44]: soup_xml.header.text                                                                         
Out[44]: 'itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">\n    \nLorem ipsum\n\n'
```

The [official docs claim](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the `xml` parser to be "the only currently supported XML parser", but it can't seem to handle commonplace HTML5 boolean attributes unless they are in the last position, which is something I can't fix on my side (the whole question has a web-scraping context). Is there a workaround / fix for the case of this specific parser?

*Note*: clearly I am aware that the `lxml` parser (or `lxml` on its own) works properly in this case, and I am only interested in using the `xml` parser in Beautiful Soup for other reasons.

Comment: What about [html5lib](https://lxml.de/html5parser.html) ? ... BeautifulSoup(html_raw, "html5lib")

Comment: there is `lxml` lib also

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I am using `beautifulsoup` to specifically get to the xpath selectors, so I think a parser that yields a valid XML tree is essential for me.

Comment: @Stack yes, and I mentioned it at the end of the post. However, I found that beautiful soup is better in opening generic html documents, so I wanted to build on that.

Comment: HTML5 is not valid XML. Trying to parse it as XML has no reason to produce any specific desirable result. Use a different parser. One that doesn't try to be XML.

Comment: @kumesana does this advice apply to a more general question of "could I use xpath selectors on arbitrary html5 documents"?

Comment: I don't know what Beautiful Soup does of XPath, but there is nothing about XPath and HTML5 that would make it difficult to use them together. If some tool claims to support one, and the other, and usibng them both doesn't behave well, then that tool isn't compliant.